# Python Printing Dictionary Key and Value side by side

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

I want a program that prints Key and Value side by side for the following code:

This is a Dictionary:

```
d = {'M': ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3'], 'F': ['Name1','Name2','Name3']}
```

I want the a program that prints in the following form:

```
M, Name1
M, Name2
M, Name3
F, Name1
F, Name2
F, Name3
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: for k in d:
    print(k)
    for v in d[k]:
        print(v)

Answer (score 4):

```
d = {'M': ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3'], 'F': ['Name1','Name2','Name3']} 

for key in d.keys():
    for value in d[key]:
        print key,value
```

edit:

A more elegant solution may be:

```
for key,value in d.iteritems():
    print key,value
```

Comment: the more elegant does not print the same output.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
d = {'M': ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3'], 'F': ['Name1','Name2','Name3']}
for a, b in d.items():
   for i in b:
       print("{}, {}".format(a, i))
```

Output:

```
M, Name1
M, Name2
M, Name3
F, Name1
F, Name2
F, Name3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate on dict key, values.

```
   for (key, values) in d.items():
        for value in values:
            print key, value
```

I'd use this code as work since it is very clead about what is does.

If you want to skill up using itertools:

```
form itertools import product
 for key, value in d.items():
     for (k, v) in product([key], value):
        print k,v
```

You may also play with cycle and zip function or zip_longest function using the key as a fillvalue.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions your could also check this and use print in the list comprehension.

Other links: 
https://spapas.github.io/2016/04/27/python-nested-list-comprehensions/
https://lerner.co.il/2015/07/23/understanding-nested-list-comprehensions-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'M': ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3'], 'F': ['Name1','Name2','Name3']}

for x in d:
    for y in d[x]:
        print(x+",",y)
```

Output

```
M, Name1
M, Name2
M, Name3
F, Name1
F, Name2
F, Name3
```