# how to print a element of a dictionary whose key is integral？

Tags: python

I am a newer to python,
i have learned print format like:`%[(dic-name)][flags][width][.precision]format`
and i want to practice it but i have a problem and i want to know why.thanks

My Python version is：

```
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
```

and i use IPython

```
 IPython 7.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
```

I have a dictionary like this：

```
dic1 = {1:"hello",2:"python"}
```

i want to print a element of the dictionary with print function.

```
print("The first element is %(1)s"%dic1)
```

But i got a KeyError like this:

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-3712b45a538a> in <module>
----> 1 print("The first element is %(1)s"%dic1)

KeyError: '1'
```

If the dictionary is：

```
dic2 = {"1":"hello","2":"python"}
```

i will get the correct result.
why the dic1 can not print like that and what's the right format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Printing Dictionary Key and Value side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47207495/python-printing-dictionary-key-and-value-side-by-side)

Comment: Try this   print("The first element is %s"%dic1[1])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usually use dictionary keys with star unpacking

```
dic1 = {"key1":"hello","key2":"python"}
print("{key1}".format(**dic1))
```

Here the keys are numbers (and not even strings but it doesn't matter anyway: to use the technique above, the arguments must be valid as python identifiers, see [what are valid keys according to Python str.format() documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42514939/what-are-valid-keys-according-to-python-str-format-documentation))

When doing `print("{1}".format(whatever))`, `format` interprets them as positional argument (2nd argument) and it fails miserably.

One solution is to pass the dictionary to `format` and query it from the format string:

```
dic1 = {1:"hello",2:"python"}

print("{dic[1]}".format(dic=dic1))
```

result:

```
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your line is that you are passing a '1' (string), not a 1 (int)

**Note**: the new `format()` method is [the recommended one](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-formatting) for python 3.x.

You can do something like:

```
print("The first element is {d[1]}".format(d=dic1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order your items by number then use **list** instead

Also you can do this:

```
dict([(1, 2), (3, 4)])
```

The result will be

```
{1: 2, 3: 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key in your dictionary is a integer, and the key in the print function is parse as map are string. That give you this error. You can print in this ways:

```
 print("The first element is ",dic1[1])
 print("The first element is {}".format(dic1[1]))
```

also you can change the keys in dict to string: `dic1 = {"1":"hello","2":"python"}`